# IDA Pro Alternative for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a good "disassembler" for JavaScript, like IDA Pro but for JS. I am looking at a chrome extension, but the JavaScript is heavily obfuscated. After deobfuscating, I am left with variable and function names like "_0xa893x5". This is using jsbeautifier.org; other deobfuscators give error. This unintuitive syntax makes it more than a little different to follow the program; is there a tool like IDA for Javascript where I can graphically trace the flow of the program from function to function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/scottrogowski/code2flow for generating callgraphs.

> Turn your Python and Javascript source code into DOT flowcharts
>
> Code2flow will sweep through your project source code looking for
>   function definitions. Then it will do another sweep looking for where
>   those functions are called. Code2flow connects the dots and presents
>   you with a flowchart estimating the functional structure of your
>   program.
>
> In other words, code2flow generates callgraphs

[image]

Comment: Is there a newer alternative? It appears this one doesnt support ecma6+

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an IDE such as WebStorm or Eclipse. You will be able to rename variables and functions, navigate to definitions and find cross-references.